# Download backup of google drive trash folder

Tags: google-drive, backup, download

I'm not really sure why but for some reason my google drive trash is full of files, and takes up nearly 3 GB.

I have the suspect there may be stuff I need in there, but I also really need to free up space on google drive.

Before emptying the bin, I'd like to **download backup of my trash folder on google drive** (without restoring the files to their original location). Is that at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into the same situation, I moved my files/folders from Bin into another folder. Moving doesn't require more space whereas copy does. Then download those files/folders.  Once I had a copy locally I moved the files back to Bin and deleted them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Linux command line utility [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) to download all the files in your Google Drive trash, as follows:

1. Give `drive` access to your Google Drive:

   ```
   drive init
   ```
2. Download the files in your Google Drive trash to the current directory on your computer ([source](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#pulling)):

   ```
   drive pull -trashed
   ```

At this time, the program is not totally reliable. Observe error messages during the download, and if needed try a second time (where it will often succeed to download files it could not at first try due to API errors, rate limits etc.). To be really sure, create a list of files in your Google trash (`drive list -recursive -trashed`) and on your local computer and compare them with `comm`.